# how to delay animation in gui button?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

i have a project AR, i have 3 (Pa,Pa2,Pa3) animations, the animations play when i press the gui button, the problem is my animation will play together , i must give delay for my animation (in this case is Pa3, see the code below), can anybody help me? this is my code

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Play : MonoBehaviour {

```
public ParticleSystem Pa;   //my animation
public ParticleSystem Pa2;
public GameObject Pa3;


void OnGUI(){


    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(8*Screen.width/10 ,Screen.height/10, Screen.width/10,Screen.height/10),"Play")){

        Pa.Play();
        Pa2.Play();

        Pa3.animation.Play("cloud");
        Pa3.animation.wrapMode = WrapMode.Once;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StartCoroutine(PlayAnimation())
IEnumerator PlayAnimation() {
    Pa.play();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Pa.length);
    Pa2.play();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Pa2.length);
    Pa3.play();
}
```